# Parsing an input string containing a dot(.) is not getting validated in ANTLR

Tags: antlr

I am having an application "abc" and I am trying to parse a job (Input string).

abc throwing error to show status of job if the job name contains dot(.)

```
»abc status -jn UpgradeJob_435_1.61.4_xyz_1000_KPI_Upgrade_confirm

Error 2001 : Command Syntax error. extraneous input 
'.61.4_xyz_1000_KPI_Upgrade_confirm' expecting

{<EOF>, JOB, JOB_OWNER, JOB_TYPE, JOB_STATUS}
Suggested Solution : Please check online help for correct syntax
```

It works fine if we give the jobname in double quotes.

For fix of the same I have added DOT rule in the command parser. Below are the snippets of the changes made.

Snippet of the Parser:

```
jobNameQuery : 

    JOB (id | DOT | stringWithQuotes)

;

jobOwnerQuery: 
    JOB_OWNER (id | DOT | stringWithQuotes)
;
```

Snippet Of Lexar:

```
DOT : '.' ;

ID: [a-zA-Z0-9_]([a-zA-Z0-9_@{}()#$%^~!`'-] | '[' | ']' )*;
```

Error Message:

Command Syntax error. extraneous input '.1' expecting {, JOB, JOB_OWNER, JOB_TYPE, JOB_STATUS}

Can someone please suggest what changes I need to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your exact requirements, either make `.` one of the allowed characters in `ID`, or change

```
(id | DOT | stringWithQuotes)
```

to

```
(
    id (DOT id)*
|   stringWithQuotes
)
```

As it is now, you allow either a quoted string, an identifier, or a single dot - not identifier intermixed with dots.

Comment: Thanks  @Jiri Tousek I will check this.